# Fatal error: Uncaught PrestaShopException PrestaShop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop, php-7, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I get an error when adding a product to the cart from a third party php page:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PrestaShopException:Fatal error in /home/var/www/html/classes/Tools.php:1109 Stack trace: 
#0 /home/var/www/html/classes/Product.php(3153): ToolsCore::displayError() 
#1 /home/var/www/html/classes/Product.php(4748): ProductCore::getPriceStatic(17, false, 0, 6, NULL, false, true, 1) 
#2 /home/var/www/html/classes/Cart.php(811): ProductCore::getProductProperties(1, Array) 
#3 /home/var/www/html/classes/Cart.php(1456): CartCore->getProducts(true) 
#4 /home/var/www/html/art/tocms/PrestaShop.php(197): CartCore->updateQty(1, 195) 
#5 /home/var/www/html/part/index.php(187): require_once('/home/var/www/h...') 
#6 {main} thrown in /home/var/www/html/classes/Tools.php on line 1109
```

What's the mistake? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you upgraded your Prestashop from version 1.6 to 1.7? and what is your current version?

Comment: Looks like something is not well initialised.
/home/var/www/html/art/tocms/PrestaShop.php is not part of prestashop. does it include '/config/config.inc.php' and '/init.php' ?

Comment: PrestaShop ver -1.7.5.2

Comment: So my code is not part of the prestashop. It is a standalone site with a list of products. I want to add a product to my cart with a preshop

Comment: Same issue for me while accessing the shipping charge on the webservice. Can you please help me on this if anyone get the solution.